# Web Scraping (Python) Multiple Request Runtime too Slow

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm working on a personal project where I need to do multiple requests to **scrape** keywords & abstract data from different pages (~ 800 requests). Every time run my program it took 30 min to **scrape** all the data.

I'm thinking two ways to speed up runtime:

1. read data into CSV file once and use panada to read data from CSV file for future reference
2. create a MySQL DB and store data in there.

Are these two approaches feasible? It would be great if I get some insights.
Thanks

Comment: FYi it’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having some experience with **scraping** you have several options as using the requests library to do your GET and Post. -> Please remember to keep the session.

Or then using a framework as [scrapy](http://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html).

The main thing to **scrape** in an optimal way is to:

1. Split your work[1];
2. Use a lots of try/exception handling and save the errors [2];
3. If you are **scraping** a lot rate-limit your requests to avoid being blocked[3];
4. Save information on each step;

And please if you are lost use the Inspect tools on your browser to see the network calls :)

[1] - A timeout is very time consuming and will stop your process until the timeout exception occurs, splitting your work will help on that.
[2] - Several errors may happen and "stop" all your work with a simple error. Using try and catching the exception will allow you to save the errors and later work on it. Saving Where you are working will allow you to resume it later.

[3] - Some sites will block you if you do several requests by minute to be reasonable.

Comment: FYi it’s __scrape__ and __scraping__ not scrap or scrapping

Comment: You are right @barny . Thank you for correcting me. 
It made me check and correct my assumptions!!

Thank you again